# ElGamal encryption security

Tags: elgamal-encryption, group-theory

Assume we have 2 prime numbers in form `p = 2q + 1`.

**Is it safe to use the cyclic group of order `p-1` instead of one with order `q` in ElGamal encryption?** I couldn't find any suitable source to explain why we should use q as order of our group and avoid `p-1`.

Most websites and sources just say:

> use cyclic group of order q

without any explanation.

**What have I tried?**
I assumed `p = 11` and therefore `q = 5`. I did all calculations of ElGamal-Encryption by considering 10 as my group order($Z_{p}^{*}$):

- *Group(G) = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}*
- *Group Order(q): 10*
- *Generator(g): 7
- *Message(m): 9*

and there was no problem in decrypting the message. So I think there is something wrong with its security!

I thinks there is no need to mention the calculations using `q = 10` But if you need them, just comment below the question to bring them into the question as an update.

Comment: Pohlig-Hellman?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it safe to use the cyclic group of order $p-1$ instead of one with order $q$ in ElGamal encryption?

1. **No**, for small values of $p$. This is the only security issue in the question's example. For modern security, $p$ should be at least in the order of $2048$‑bit (rather than $4$‑bit for $p=11$ in the question), and not close to a prime power. Anything below says $512$‑bit ($\approx155$ decimal digits) is quite vulnerable to the recovery of the private key from the public key
2. **No**, if *«use»* refers to the plaintext set. Problem is: from the ciphertext of [ElGamal encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ElGamal_encryption#Encryption), an adversary can find if the plaintext $m$ is a [quadratic residue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue) modulo $p$ or not (that is, if $m^{(p-1)/2}\bmod p$ is $1$ or $p-1$). How is left as an exercise to the reader. Reference: Dan Boneh, Antoine Joux, and Phong Q. Nguyen's [*Why Textbook ElGamal and RSA Encryption Are Insecure*](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F3-540-44448-3_3.pdf) (in [proceedings of AsiaCrypt 2000](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-44448-3_3)), recommended in [Yehuda Lindell's answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/88534/555).

   This property breaks security under Chosen Plaintext Attack, and even weaker notions. It can be a practical weakness: if it was enciphered a name on the public class roll (using a large $p$), we could rule out about half the names given the ciphertext. If it was a coin toss with fixed public values for head and tail, for about 50% of the choices of these values, the coin toss would leak.

   The safe and usual option is to restrict the plaintext to the group of quadratic residues, that is to $m$ with $m^{(p-1)/2}\bmod p=1$. That happens (perhaps by chance) to be the case in the question's example, since $9^5\bmod11=1$.
3. **Yes**, if *«use»* refers to the set for $g$ and the issues above are taken care of: it is safe to use $g$ that generates the whole cyclic group. That's the case in the question's example, since $7^5\bmod11=11-1$.

   However that's unusual because we must restrict the plaintext (per 2), and customarily we restrict $g$ to the same group, so as to be back to ElGamal encryption (re‑)stated in a generic group. That's what sources do when they just say: «use a cyclic group of prime order $q$».

---

As stated, the textbook solution to the problem in (2) is to restrict the plaintext to the subgroup of quadratic residues. When we encipher a small discrete set, that's fine: we can handpick the $m_i$ representing the set elements.

But when we encipher arbitrary data, like a name on the class roll, that won't do. In practice that's solved using [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_encryption). But if we want to remain closer to straight ElGamal encryption in $\mathbb Z_p^*$, a workable method goes:

- The plaintext $m$ is restricted to an interval $[0,m_{\text{max}}]$ with $m_{\text{max}}<(p-1)/2$
- To encipher $m$ in that interval, the sender computes $m'\gets(m+1)^2\bmod p$ and encrypts that using normal ElGamal encryption. Note that $m'$ is a quadratic residue, thwarting the attack.
- After the receiver deciphers $m'$, they find the smallest of the two modular square roots of $m'$ (modulo $p$) using e.g. [Tonelli-Shanks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm), then subtract one to find $m$.

Beware of side channels in the implementation!

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question can be found in the paper [Why Textbook ElGamal and RSA Encryption Are Insecure](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwit2c-z8Y7vAhXpXRUIHTlEBNgQFjABegQIBBAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Fcontent%2Fpdf%2F10.1007%2F3-540-44448-3_3.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0XL9rNArNY8iajFWJRoPUe) by Boneh et al. It is an easy paper to read and worthwhile going through the details there.